# Laser / photosensor pair or similar

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm looking for a laser / photosensor pair (or product of similar function) for detecting when a beam is interrupted (no more than 3ft apart, probably more like 1ft).

I'd like these to run off of 5V, since I'm using an Arduino. My main requirement, however, is that these parts have nice housings, ideally with some mounting screw holes or something along those lines. This is going into a project where sturdiness and durability are important.

I don't know how to search for parts like what I am looking for. Could you please point me either to some good product sources, give me some better keywords for searching, or link me directly to potentially useful products?

Comment: How about an ultrasonic sensor, maybe combined with infrared? Should be cheaper and easier to use.

Comment: I can't see how that would be cheaper. Ultrasonic sensors are fairly expensive and I'd also be worried that the beam wouldn't be interrupted at all since the whole project is going to be housed in a small metal shed (not a box, a shed, with standing room).
Infrared may be a good solution in most cases, but this is being used in close proximity to a very hot charcoal stove, so that's no good.

Comment: I think the choice of which sensor to use should be determined by your operating environment. In noisy audio environments ultra sonic sensors tends to suffer (eg see p 6 of http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~tomlin/papers/conferences/hrwdjt04_dasc.pdf). The problem with lasers are that as the distance between transmitter and receiver increases it gets very difficult to accurately align the beam. The smallest bump will cause a permanent failure. I'd recommend a plain IR beam (especially since it seems you're planning to use it in doors). Try googling "IR Beam arduino". Good luck.

Comment: If however you're set on using a laser, any LDR should do the trick, please refer to the following web page for spectrum characteristic as well as response times: http://triyot.com/en/index.php?lang=en&page_id=light-dependent-resistor-LDR

Comment: As it stands, this sounds very much like a *[shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* and this type of question isn't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical,
answerable questions based on actual problems that you 
face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)*. Take a look at [ask] and 
[about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and hopefully we can 
modify this question into something a bit more answerable.

Comment: If you could explain the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking for a source for a part you have already decided on, then someone may be able to suggest a solution you haven't thought of yet.